# @JsonIgnore doesn't work in Scala case class

Tags: json, scala

I have a simple case class

```
case class Project(@JsonIgnore id: Option[UUID], name: Option[String])
```

I am using com.fasterxml.jackson

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.4
org.skinny-framework.com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.8.4
```

...

```
private val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
mapper.writeValueAsString(project)
```

writes id into resulting json despite @JsonIgnore

what am i doing wrong?

**update:**

a current workaround:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("id"))
case class Project(id: Option[UUID], name: Option[String])
```

this works well :)

Comment: Thanks for updating with your resolution. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation just ends up on the constructor parameter instead of field.

From scala [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/annotation/meta/index.html)

```
By default, annotations on (val-, var- or plain) constructor parameters end up on the parameter, not on any other entity
```

You need to put the annotation on the field using scala's meta annotation. Try this

```scala
import scala.annotation.meta._
case class Project(@(JsonIgnore @field) id: Option[UUID], name: Option[String])
```